# x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc compile assembly error

Tags: gcc, assembly, cygwin

I run a simple piece x86-64 assembly code of hello world.

```
    .global main

    .text
main:                                
    mov     $message, %rdi       
    sub     $8, %rsp             
    call    puts                 
    add     $8, %rsp             
    ret  

message:
    .asciz "Hello, World"
```

I use gcc_4.8.2 under cygwin to compile this program under my 64-bit windows os.

```
gcc -o helloworld helloworld.s
```

but the compiler always give me the error:

```
/tmp/ccylxw5q.o:fake:(.text+0x3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.text'
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does your compiler create 64 bit code? If its cygwin, it might not.

Comment: Actually it creates 64 bit code, otherwise the compiler will report the error of misusing register.

Comment: I suggest you run `gcc -S` on the C "Hello, World" code so that you can see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Under `gas` (which is invoked by `gcc`) you need to use the `movabsq` mnemonic if you want to load a 64 bit immediate. Otherwise the assembler will use the 32 bit sign-extending mov, which is indicated by the relocation type of `32S` as well. The final address of the `message` might not be represented as a 32 bit sign-extended value under certain memory layouts which is probably causing the truncation warning.